# How do I specify the button that I want to activate a function?

Tags: python, kivy

When I press a button the `check_streak()` function is called. I want only to compare that buttons time aka 'honey' to `time.time()`. Instead of printing a response to one buttons 'honey' every buttons 'honey' is compared and a response is printed for each one. Since the button is created in a for loop I'm not sure how I could specify that I only want to compare that specific button. How would I fix this? code:

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self): # build() returns an instance
        self.store = JsonStore("streak.json") # file that stores the streaks:


        return presentation

    # Gets the value of delta (code I may never understand lol)
    def item_generator(self, json_input, lookup_key):
        if isinstance(json_input, dict):
            for k, v in json_input.items():
                if k == lookup_key:
                    yield v
                else:
                    yield from self.item_generator(v, lookup_key)
        elif isinstance(json_input, list):
            for item in json_input:
                yield from self.item_generator(item, lookup_key)

    def check_streak(self, instance):
        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)
            values = self.item_generator(data, 'delta')



        for honey in values:
            if honey > time.time():
                print("early")

            if honey == time.time():
                print("on time")

            if honey < time.time():
                print("late")
```

```
def display_btn(self):
        # display the names of the streaks in a list on PageTwo
        for key in self.store:
            streak_button = Button(text=key, on_press=self.check_streak)
            self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.add_widget(streak_button)
```

I currently have 3 buttons in the program. When I press a button, I expect to print 'early' but instead I print, 'early early early' because there are 3 buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kivy Widget » touch event bubbling](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#widget-touch-event-bubbling)

> When you catch touch events between multiple widgets, you often need
>   to be aware of the order in which these events are propagated. In
>   Kivy, events bubble up from the first child upwards through the other
>   children. If a widget has children, the event is passed through its
>   children before being passed on to the widget after it.

[Kivy » Touch event basics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> ...
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

## Solution

- Create a `class CustomButton` with inheritance of `Button`
- Implement `on_touch_down` method
- Check for collision using `collide_point()` function

### Snippets

```
class CustomButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.dispatch('on_press')
            return True
        return super(CustomButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)    
...

    def display_btn(self):
        # display the names of the streaks in a list on PageTwo
        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

            for value in self.item_generator(data, 'delta'):
                print(f"\tvalue={value}")
                streak_button = CustomButton(text=str(value), on_press=self.check_streak)
            self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.add_widget(streak_button)
```

## Example

The following example illustrates the suggested solution.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
import json


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenTwo>:
    GridLayout:
        id: streak_zone
        cols: 2
""")


class CustomButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f"\nCustomButton.on_touch_down: text={self.text}")
            self.dispatch('on_press')
            return True
        return super(CustomButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.store = JsonStore("streak.json")
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.display_btn(), 0.5)

        return ScreenTwo()

    def check_streak(self, instance):
        print(f"\ncheck_streak:")
        honey = float(instance.id)
        print(f"\tdelta={honey}")
        if honey > time.time():
            print("\t\tearly")

        if honey == time.time():
            print("\t\ton time")

        if honey < time.time():
            print("\t\tlate")

    def display_btn(self):
        print(f"\ndisplay_btn:")

        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

            for value in data.values():
                if value['delta'] is not None:
                    print(f"action={value['action']}, delta={value['delta']}")
                    streak_button = CustomButton(id=str(value['delta']), text=value['action'], on_press=self.check_streak)
                    self.root.ids.streak_zone.add_widget(streak_button)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: I added the CustomButton class and added `honey = StreakButton()` above the for loop, however, I still get the same problem. Multiple button responses are printed instead of just one.

Comment: Why you instantiate button, `honey = StreakButton()`? Please post your updated code.

Comment: I actually removed that part, realizing there was no point. I still get the same result though.

Comment: In the JSON file provided, there are two keys and two values for *delta*. Whenever a button is pressed, one will see two results. I have added an example as an illustration. Please refer to updated post for details.

Comment: I followed the example and found that using the `schedule_once()` function only duplicates the buttons I have so I got rid of that. Following the rest of the code still results in the same problem of printing "delta" twice even though I only press one button.

Comment: You don't need`Clock.schedule_once(...)` in your app. I have it in my example for demo purposes. You app will print `delta` twice because there are two `delta` with difference values in your JSON file.

Comment: That's my problem. Is there a way for the button to only print `delta` value assigned to it?

Comment: When you instantiate the `CustomButton`, assign delta to it. You have to also change method `check_streak()`.

Comment: Please refer to updated post for details i.e. display buttons as per `delta`.

Comment: This solution makes the buttons display the value of `delta`, also when I press a button the application closes and I get a `TypeError: check_streak() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: You need to add `instance` into method `check_streak()`. Please refer to updated example for details.